# Python print buffering

Tags: python, printing, executable, arcgis

Let me rephrase my previous question.
I just created a tool in ArcGIS using pythong as script language. The tool executes (runs) an outside program using the subprocess.popen. When I run the tool from ArcGSIS, a window appears that only shows the following.

```
Executing: RunFLOW C:\FLOW C:\FLOW\FLW.bat
Start Time: Mon Nov 30 16:50:37 2009
Running script RunFLOW...
Completed script RuFLOW...
Executed (RunFLOW) successfully.
End Time: Mon Nov 30 16:50:48 2009 (Elapsed Time: 11.00 seconds)
```

The script is as follows

```
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, subprocess
# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
# Read the parameter values:
#  1: input workspace
prj_fld = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
Flow_bat = gp.GetParameterAsText(1)
os.chdir(prj_fld)
p=subprocess.Popen(Flow_bat,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = p.communicate()[0]
print '\tstdout:', repr(stdout_value)
```

When I run the same program from command window, it prints a screen full of information (date, number of iteration, etc.). I want to see all this information in the window that appears after I run the model from ArcGIS in addition to what it is being printing right now. 
I tried print, communicate, flush but couldn't be able to do it. Any suggestions?

When I run the script as it is right now, it runs the executable but it gives an error as follows

```
ERROR 999998: There are no more files.
```

Thanks

Comment: 1.  Please omit confusing and irrelevant junk like "Let me rephrase my previous question."  Then, please look on the right side of the page for formatting hints.

Comment: @Mesut: reformatted your question: please refer to the editor help to learn how to do code blocks

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about ArcGIS, so I may be shooting in the dark here, but...if you want stdout, you usually don't want the `communicate()` method.  You want something like this:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(Flow_bat,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = p.stdout.read()
```

The `communicate()` method is used for *interacting* with a process.  From the documentation:

```
Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from stdout
and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  Wait for process to
terminate.
```

I'm guessing that when ArcGIS runs your script that `stdin` is not connected and causes the script to exit for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried added the script below
p=subprocess.Popen(Flow_bat,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line
retval=p.wait()

with this script my program is executed (can check it from the putputs) but still it doesnt print the command window information on my toll progress window.
I tried stdout_value=p.stdout.read() and print it but it didnt work either.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure what else to suggest.  I don't have access to ArcGIS to I'm sort of flying blind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are aware of this or not but I use:

```
gp.AddMessage('blah blah')
```

to get messages to appear in the ArcGIS processing window. Its a method of the geoprocessor object, the library you import in Python to access the ArcGIS engine. You would already have imported this library if you are doing any geoprocessing.